# Are we already migrating questions to Joomla Beta?

Tags: discussion

I read on one of the meta questions last week that questions from StackOverflow won't be migrated to the beta in case the beta fails (which we will prevent from happening) and it then gets lost. But I just came across [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-to-extend-component-helper-class) and saw that it was migrated from StackOverflow.

So are we already going to migrate questions to the beta?

Comment: Meh, if it were up to me, all question with the Joomla tag on SO would be migrated over here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can migrate questions to any Stack Exchange site, including those in public beta. However, this is a manual process, so it does not happen automatically.

So "we" are not migrating anything, but moderators from StackOverflow (or other network sites) can do that.

Questions older than 60 cannot be migrated, so basically only newer questions can be migrated.

Comment: Interesting. But should the "we" (that are here and mods there) among us then migrate questions to this beta or hold off on it for now?

Comment: It's a judgement call. If a moderator thinks a question has more chances getting answered here, it can migrate it, I don't know of any restrictions.

Comment: So we should check SO for Joomla questions and flag them for migration.

Comment: If they are out of the scope defined for SO or if they don't have any answers yet. Unfortunately Joomla does not show in the suggestion for websites where the question can be migrated.

Comment: Also, when saying moderators can, it is only moderators of that site. So even though Valentin and I are moderators for Joomla SE, we can't go to Stack Overflow and migrate questions here. It has to be migrated by moderators of Stack Overflow.

Comment: i think you can flag the post as other, then write a note that the question would be better off on the joomla SE

Comment: For the public beta to succeed we will likely need a significant proportion of the Joomla questions being asked over on SO and the other SE sites to make it over to the Joomla SE site